# Problems with functional tests after TYPO3 9.5.1 was released

Tags: php, phpunit, typo3, functional-testing, typo3-9.x

After the release of TYPO3 9.5.1, I have problems with my functional tests.

> The package "backend" depends on "recordlist" which is not present in the system.

In TYPO3 9.5.0 there was a missing requirement in ext:backend for ext:recordlist
https://review.typo3.org/#/c/58575/

This is now merged into TYPO3 9.5.1 but this exactly gives me a problem on how I do my tests.

I shouldn't be needed for me to boot a full-blown TYPO3 to run my tests should it?

The tests and how it's done can be seen here:

https://travis-ci.org/AOEpeople/TYPO3-Google-Tag-Manager/jobs/448321932
https://github.com/AOEpeople/TYPO3-Google-Tag-Manager/blob/typo3v9/.travis.yml

Please help elaborate if I'm doing something wrong, or if the is a problem with the latest TYPO3?

The unittests isn't a Problem by the way, and ^7.6 and ^8.7 don't have any problems either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was an issue in `nimut/testing-framework` and was [fixed 2 days ago](https://github.com/Nimut/testing-framework/commit/fa6c60239344f9023677c8ec98b49b82ecf83235). So you just need to update to [version 4.1.4](https://github.com/Nimut/testing-framework/releases/tag/4.1.4) or add `recordlist` to the `$coreExtensionsToLoad` in the meantime. Make sure to explicitly require `typo3/cms-recordlist` in case you test against older TYPO3 versions too.

Comment: In the meantime version 4.1.4 has been released which includes the fix.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the version to my answer.